# What is the "likes" field from an FB Open Graph GET og.likes request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, httprequest, facebook-like

I've implemented functionality to Like a non-FB URL in a cross-platform mobile app (Phonegap) I'm developing, and part of functionality is that I need to find out if a user has liked a URL before, hence a GET on the og.likes object. In the result of this request there's a field in the og.likes data that I'm unsure about.

My request:

```
GET me/og.likes?access_token={AccessToken}&object={EncodedExternalURL}
```

The response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "_____", 
      "from": {
        "id": "______", 
        "name": "______"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2015-01-12T06:17:24+0000", 
      "end_time": "2015-01-12T06:17:24+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2015-01-12T06:17:24+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "______", 
        "namespace": "______", 
        "id": "______"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "object": {
          "id": "____", 
          "url": "____", 
          "type": "website", 
          "title": "____"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "og.likes", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": { // <-- this guy here and its properties
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "____"
  }
}
```

What is the `likes` field? And the sub properties of `count`, `can_like`, `user_likes`? Is it that other users can like this Like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`likes` field is for manage the likes that this like has. Users can like or comment a like.